# What package I should install for 'pcre-devel'?

Tags: ubuntu

I need to install the `pcre-devel` package to compile `lighttpd` on Ubuntu:

> configure: error: pcre-config not found, install the pcre-devel package or build with --without-pcre

Can you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try using `apt-cache search`, e.g.,

```
apt-cache search pcre
```

For me this turns up a lot so I grep for the keyword `dev`.

This turns up `libpcre3-dev` and `libpcre++-dev`.

`lighttpd` will use one of those no doubt.

So if your search shows `libpcre3-dev`, you can install using:
`sudo apt install libpcre3-dev`

However, is there any reason you're compiling lighttpd yourself?
Why not install using `apt`?
Including `lighttpd-dev`, `lighttpd-doc` and some related modules.

Comment: Thank you. I get it to run and use 'lighttpd.conf' (provided in doc directory). But when I hit the browser with 'http://127.0.0.1' I can't see anything. Any idea?

 ps -ef |grep lighttpd
root     10315     1  0 18:06 ?        00:00:00 ./lighttpd -f lighttpd.conf

Comment: Check the log files.  Make sure there is nothing else using the port configured in lighttpd.conf.  Check the configuration file as well.

Answer (score 8):

On Ubuntu 9.10:

```
$ apt-cache search pcre | grep -- -dev
libpcre3-dev - Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library - development files
libghc6-pcre-light-dev - Haskell library for Perl 5-compatible regular expressions
libghc6-regex-base-dev - GHC 6 library providing an API for regular expressions
libpcre++-dev - C++ wrapper class for pcre (development)
libpcre-ocaml-dev - OCaml bindings for PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression)
$
```

That would be `libpcre3-dev` for C, or `libpcre++-dev` for C++.

By the same token, the `lighthttpd` already exists as well:

```
$ apt-cache search lighttpd
collectd - statistics collection and monitoring daemon
lighttpd - A fast webserver with minimal memory footprint
lighttpd-dev - Development files for lighttpd
lighttpd-doc - Documentation for lighttpd
lighttpd-mod-cml - Cache meta language module for lighttpd
lighttpd-mod-magnet - Control the request handling module for lighttpd
lighttpd-mod-mysql-vhost - MySQL-based virtual host configuration for lighttpd
lighttpd-mod-trigger-b4-dl - Anti-deep-linking module for lighttpd
lighttpd-mod-webdav - WebDAV module for lighttpd
mongrel-cluster - Mongrel plugin to manage a cluster of Mongrel servers
mono-fastcgi-server - ASP.NET backend for FastCGI webservers - default version
mono-fastcgi-server1 - ASP.NET 1.1 backend for FastCGI webservers
mono-fastcgi-server2 - ASP.NET 2.0 backend for FastCGI webservers
$
```